# What is a good, lightweight database to use for a small F# winforms project?

Tags: database, f#

I have a project I'm thinking of doing in F#, but I'm still very new to the language. I'll need a simple database, hopefully something easy to use. Would sqlite work well for an F# project? Other suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it's so much a question of a particular database technology that can work with F#--if you've got an ODBC driver, it can be made to work with pretty much any .Net language.  Pick one (SQLite seems a good option) and start coding.

Comment: +1 on SQL Compact Edition, and a tangential question: why WinForms and not WPF, a more uptodate UI technology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SqlLite is a very popular lightweight database engine that supports a .Net binding layer which is accessible from F#.  It probably the best option for your scenario.

This CodeProject article details how to use C# to bind to SqlLite and is easily transferable to an F# scenario

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx

Comment: Bear in mind that .Net support for SQLite uses a .Net wrapper around the native SQLite code, hence it is not a pure .Net solution and you will need to install a different dll for different platforms, e.g. 32bit and 64bit Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be [SQL Server 2008 Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx). I don't have any experience with it myself, but my understanding is that it is just a `dll` that can be easily distributed with your project.

The programming API is standard ADO.NET (which can be easily used from F#). It also supports LINQ, so if you wanted, you could also call it with F# LINQ (FLINQ) from CodePlex.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/), it's just an object store, so it's [pretty simple](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/net35/tutorial/docs/First.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) embedded can be a good choice too

> The embedded version is an amazing
>   variation of the server. It is a fully
>   featured Firebird server packed in
>   just a few files. It is very easy to
>   deploy, since there is no need to
>   install the server. It is ideal for
>   CDROM catalogs, demos or standalone
>   desktop applications.